# Filtering NSArray of NSDictionary based on a dictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a NSArray of NSDictionary and I want to filter out a specific dictionary from it. With my below code I am getting nil matchedDicts. Am I doing something wrong?

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"locationID = %@", @"949"];
NSArray *matchedDicts = [aLocationsList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];

{
    locationID = 2023;
    locationName = "Customer";
    sortOrder = 0;
},
{
    locationID = 2024;
    locationName = "My Loc";
    sortOrder = 1;
},
{
    locationID = 949;
    locationName = "His Loc";
    sortOrder = 2;
}
)
```

Comment: Are the numbers in your dictionaries numbers, not strings? Try logging [aLocationList[0][@"locationID"] class] and see what it gives you.

Comment: Its a NSString and it prints __NSCFString.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure aLocationList is not nil where you have this code. Also, when you say "getting nil matchedDicts", what do you mean? Are you getting nil, or an empty array, if you log matchedDicts?

Comment: I am getting output as nil.

Comment: @Abhinav: If matchedDicts is nil then aLocationsList must already be nil.

Comment: @MartinR Actually, its not. I tried changing the predicate and did the NSString comparison and it worked. Since this is not a NSInteger simple equal won't work. Please see my posted answer.

Comment: @Abhinav: I am glad that you solved your problem. But `=` in a *predicate* works perfectly for strings (I tested this and @rdelmar as well, as it seems). And if the predicate would not match any element of the array, then the result would be an empty array, and not nil.

Comment: @MartinR That makes sense. I shall see why it didn't work for me with simple "=" in NSPredicate.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it using the block format instead:

```
-(NSArray*)filterArrayOfDictionaries:(NSArray*)arr
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSNumber *locationID = dict[@"locationID"];

        if([locationID intValue]==949)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];

    return [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out with below piece of code:

```
NSPredicate *aLocationFilterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *allLocations, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([allLocations[kRunnerLocationIDKey] isEqualToString:aCachedLocationID]) ? YES : NO;
}];

NSArray *aMatchedLocation = [aLocationsList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aLocationFilterPredicate];
```